# Elements not adapting to container size

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a login page, and I am using @media to have a better css interface for mobile users. [image] as you can see in this image, the inputs, and buttons are not the width of 100%. So does anyone know how I can make the inputs and the button be as wide as the container?

Attached, is my some relevant code to try to see whats wrong. Thank you!

CSS and HTML:

```css
@media (max-width:500px) {
  input {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-top: 0px;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-right: 0px;
  }
  login-box {
    width: 90vw;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    display: grid;
  }
  login-button {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  login-box-content {
    display: grid;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <all>
    <login-wrapper>
      <login-box>
        <login-box-content>
          <login-title>Login</login-title>
          <login-input>
            <login-label>Username</login-label>
            <Br>
            <input></input>
          </login-input><br>
          <login-input>
            <login-label>Password</login-label>
            <Br>
            <input></input>
          </login-input>
          <login-button onclick="pressed()">
            <login-button-content>Login</login-button-content>
          </login-button>
        </login-box-content>
      </login-box>
    </login-wrapper>
  </all>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I have checked your code and it's working as intended, when the viewport width is lower than 500px. There may be some other other CSS code that you have not included here interfering with your desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm so stupid...

**The answer is:**
The media part has to be below existing css or else it won't override the existing css rules!